# setFormula question. Howto get input from script itself inside the formula

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a formula that I want to write in specific cells (based on background color). The code below kinda works, but the formula itself stays static. (A41 stays A41 in every cell I put this formula in)

I want the formula to take into account in which row it is being placed. I have to break the formula up with { or & or +, I tried multiple times, without success.

Anyone have a hint?

```
        var gray2 = "#efefef";
  //var nocolor = "#ffffff";
  var rangeList = colors.reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
  var row = i + 1;
    if (a == gray2) ar.push(`C${row}:C${row}`);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  false);  

sheetbalk.getRangeList(rangeList).setFormula("=IFERROR(SUM(filter(Transacties!$C:C;TEXT(Transacties!$A:A;\"yyyyMMMM\") = $D$3 & $C$3;regexmatch(Transacties!$F:F; A41)));\"Geen gegevens\")");
```

From the the following part

```
Transacties!$F:F; A41)
```

A41 needs to be in the same row, for example A42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `... A" + (41 + row) + ")...` or similar work?

Comment: Hi, I think I tried that before, but with this it stops at:   $C$3;regexmatch Transacties!$F:F; 
I will continue trying, but ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the exact code expression you're using for it? (And by stops at, you mean the formula string doesn't contain any of the characters after "...$F:F;", right?)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it

```
sheetbalk.getRangeList(rangeList).setFormula('=IFERROR(SUM(filter(Transacties!$C:C;TEXT(Transacties!$A:A;\"yyyyMMMM\") = $D$3 & $C$3;regexmatch (Transacties!$F:F; A' + (row) + ')));\"Geen //gegevens\")');
```